# I don't see navigation color option in one of my templates in salesforce community builder

Tags: community-builder

I am not seeing the Navigation style option in the theme option for one of template I am using but I am not sure what is the difference between one displaying this option. Is it API version or some setting I can change to display the Navigation options? Or it is only available from salesforce template?

[image: Navigation color option]

My builder only display a few options

[image]

[image]

Comment: It should be available one you click on the navigation bar and customize that in the builder

Comment: When you say "custmoize" is it adding menu item to the default navigation bar? or adding another navigation?

Comment: In the builder when you click on the navigation bar.

Comment: as you see in the attached image I don't get navigation option i the color section. not sure if API version thing or some setting I don't know.

Comment: The screenshots are from builder left buttons. In the builder click on the Header where you see the logo, search bar and user profile, the top bar

Comment: I can select Navigation Menu but I should be changing the color from the Theme > Color right?

Comment: Each templates comes with different sets of customisation options. You'll need to choose one that suits your needs.

Comment: do you happen to know which metadata I should be looking at in order to change that? I have been going through the metadata bardningSets and CommunityTemplateDefinitions as well as CommunityThemeDefinition but not sure which one will trigger the navigation menu styling to show up

Comment: I noticed warning message (please see the newly attached image) in the theme which doesn't show the navigation text color. Is this mean my template is deprecated?